# combine groupby and resample

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

i want to calculate the sum per week

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2']
               ,  'date':['2021-01-01','2021-01-02',
               '2021-01-03','2021-01-04','2021-01-05',
               '2021-01-06','2021-01-07','2021-01-08'],
           'revenue':[5,3,2,
                      10,12,2,
                      1,0]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

expected output:

```
  2020-12-28  x1.   10
  2021-01-04    x1.   10
  2021-01-04.   x2.   15
```

**I did**

```
df.groupby('id', 'date')["revenue"].resample('W-Mon', on='date', closed='left', label='left').sum()
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? The expected output is not very clear

Comment: `df.assign(year=df['date'].dt.isocalendar().year, week=df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week).groupby(['year','week','id'])['revenue'].sum()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear of the output you are looking for.
**Solution:**

```
df.groupby('id').resample('W-Mon', on='date').sum().reset_index()
```

We can use above code, if we want to get weekly(on Monday) sum of revenue by id.

**Output:**

```
    id  date    revenue
0   x1  2021-01-04  20
1   x2  2021-01-11  15
```

**Edit:**

**For expected output:**

```
    id  date    revenue
0   x1  2020-12-28  10
1   x1  2021-01-04  10
2   x2  2021-01-04  15
```

**Solution**

```
df = df.groupby('id').resample('W', on='date').sum().reset_index()
df['date'] = df.date - pd.Timedelta('6D')
df
```

**Single line solutions**

```
df.groupby('id').resample('W-Mon', on='date', closed='left', label='left').sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you but i miss this week 2020-12-28. I want to sum the revenue groupby id and begin of the week (from monday).

Comment: 2020.12.28 was Tuesday and 2021-01-04 was Monday.
If you want to get the data weekly you can either get Monday's or Tuesdays.
If you want forward week revenue by back date i.e if you want o have date as 2020-12-27 and revenue sum between(2020-12-27 and 2021-12-03) then you can subtract output date by 7.

Comment: Hello, no 2020-12-28 was monday that's why

Comment: In that case we can subtract 6D from the output, updated the solution. Hope that solves the problem!

Comment: thank you @Utsav im getting this error ValueError: cannot insert id, already exists.

Comment: which command are you running?
This error states that you are trying to insert 'id' column in df which is already present.

Comment: i tried your solution ,this one: df = df.groupby('id').resample('W', on='date').sum().reset_index()
df['date'] = df.date - pd.Timedelta('6D')

Comment: This should work!
I tried and its working perfectly. If it's not working for you, please share all the steps you are doing and complete stack trace of error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, OP's tried code is already very close.  We just need little bit tweaks, as follows:

```
df.groupby('id').resample('W-Mon', on='date', closed='left', label='left')["revenue"].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id       date  revenue
0  x1 2020-12-28       10
1  x1 2021-01-04       10
2  x2 2021-01-04       15
```

**What's changed on top of OP's code:**

- replaced `df.groupby('id', 'date')` by `df.groupby('id')`:  `df.groupby('id', 'date')` is a wrong syntax to [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).  Here, instead of grouping by the 2 columns `['id', 'date']` like `df.groupby(['id', 'date'])` *(with square brackets)*, `'date'` is passed (incorrectly) as the 2nd parameter to [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), which instead should be accepting an `axis=` parameter.  Hence, resulting in error `ValueError: No axis named date for object type DataFrame`.   Actually, we don't need to group by `date` when we are going to be immediately followed by [`.resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)
- moved `["revenue"]` from before [`.resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to after it:   If we had already specified a column before calling [`.resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), then the [`.resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) call would then be called based on the Pandas series of column `revenue` and cannot access the column `date`.  Hence, resulting in error `KeyError: 'The grouper name date is not found'`
- added [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) at the end so that the column `id` which had been set as index by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) will return back to data columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pd.Grouper`:

```
df.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(freq='W-Mon', key='date', closed='left', label='left')])\
  .sum()\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id       date  revenue
0  x1 2020-12-28       10
1  x1 2021-01-04       10
2  x2 2021-01-04       15
```